# Откуда этот обьект __proto__?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, вот у нас есть функция-конструктор, дальше я создаю сам экземпляр этого конструктора.

1. Сам экземпляр с методом и с `__proto__` на другой объект
2. Не могу понять что это за промежуточный объект и откуда он появился? Почему свойство constructor не записано в сам объект, а в `__proto__` не ссылка на `Object`?

   ```
   function User() {
       this.sayHi = function() {
           alert('Hi');
       }
   }

   let foo = new User();
   ```

[image: Консоль браузера]

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype

Comment: этот объект берется из свойства `User.prototype`: `Object.getPrototypeOf(new User()) === User.prototype; // true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Этот объект берется из свойства User.prototype:
>   Object.getPrototypeOf(new User()) === User.prototype; // true

Спасибо Grundy за ответ, жаль что он написал его в комментариях под вопросом (не могу отметить как правильное решение)